# Access external network devices from router's internal network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, routing

When I am connected to my broadband (PPPoE network e.g. `Network A`) via Ethernet cable, I can access any device connected to my `Network A` as normal.

But when I am connected to a Router (configured to serve as a DHCP server) from the same `Network A`, I am unable to access `Network A` devices and can only access devices connected with my router, giving an error message that "Windows can't access \\192.168.100.254".

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4U6U.png)

My router internal network has Statically assigned IP Addresses like `192.167.1.100~110` via DHCP. I tried the following  configurations on a couple of routers both are little old,

- Setting up `DMZ host` on Tenda N3 and Tenda W302R
- Disabling `AP isolation` On Tenda W302R (N3 doesn't provide this feature),

But both of these configurations doesn't solves the problem I am facing. `AP Isolation` only controls visibility inside the router's network not what I am shooting for, i.e. enable visibility of the outside network as well.

I have something similar to the following network configuration, I am not exactly sure how the network A devices are physically configured, there may be a series of switching devices in between.

[Network Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMngl.jpg)

I am not much of a networking geek so how can I be connected via WIFI and still access all `network A` devices and my router's internal network devices as well.

**EDIT:**

I have reverted router's internal addresses to `192.168.1.100~110`

**EDIT 2:**

There is no intermediary device like modem etc. present in between the router and the Network A, Router directly uses the PPPOE credentials to connect to the internet.

Comment: 192.167? Why is your LAN using IP address belonging to Consortium GARR, Italy?

Comment: Grawity is right guy, it's a publicly routable address. If a router doesn't find a route in it's table it sends it out to the internet to be resolved...

Comment: @grawity well my router initially had addresses similar to 192.168.1.100~110, then I changed it thinking that the issues might be that it tries looking for 192.168.100.254 in the internal network, and fails to find the device in question. But this  theory didn't result fruitful.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart so you are suggesting that I should change it back to the default; 192.168?

Comment: @grawity, I have reverted router's internal addresses back to 192.168.1.100~110, but that doesn't changes anything about my problem.

Comment: Yes sir, valid class c private addresses are 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

Comment: Gimme a sec, I'll post instructions on how to do this. Unless grawity wants it.

Comment: Is network-a in the same physical location as the network you are trying to bridge? Or is it crossing a WAN link?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart you can refer to the image named as network config, my router's network is internal and network A is the external network, with which I am only connected via the router's WAN port.

Comment: This is ADSL dial-up correct? The diagram is missing some crucial info. If you can, please add any intermediate devices in the diagram, and any of the addressing info you know. I'm assuming there is a modem or interface device in-between your tetra router and network-a correct? Or is the tetra doing  the ppoe dial-in?

Comment: I have updated my question. Basically I don't know the exact physical layout of anything beyond my router, which connects to network A via an Ethernet cable plugged into its WAN port.